# C++ communication between objects

Tags: c++, object, observer-pattern

I'm sure this kind of question has been asked (and answered) before, so please link me to a previous discussion if so...

In C++, say I have an object of type ClassA which includes a private member variable object of type ClassB. How would I go about calling a reference to the ClassA object *within* ClassB?

I am using the Observer Design Pattern where the ClassA object is the 'subject' and an object within ClassB, say of type ClassC, is an 'observer' of the ClassA object. Therefore when initialising object ClassC within ClassB one of its parameters needs to be a reference to its 'subject' object.

Comment: why don't you just pass ClassA's reference?

Comment: it will be better understandable if you post the code.

Comment: @akappa Yes thats all I needed to do. I was thinking to much into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Briefly:

```
struct A;

struct B : C {
  B(A &a) : c(a) { }

  C c;
};

struct A {
  A() : b(*this) { }

  private:
    B b;
};
```

B gets no special access to A just because it is a member.  You must explicitly pass the reference.